How can I customize the URL structure for blog posts in Bitrix to remove subsections?
I'm working on a website that has been developed by Bitrix. I'd like to change the URL structure for the blog posts, but it seems impossible to do so! Here's the structure:
Within the "Content" section, there is a designated subsection for "Articles". When I craft articles directly within this segment, the thumbnail displays on the blog page, but attempting to access the article page results in a 404 error.
So, I had to create a subsection for it work, and since it's named as "blog" my URLs are like: website.com/articles/blog/article-title.
I want the URLs to be: website.com/articles/article-title or website.com/blog/article-title, but I'm unable to find a solution. I've tried editing the Element list page URL and Section page URL in the Content section, but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Hello. You can create an information block “blog” in the “Content” section next to “Articles” and do everything by analogy with “Articles” in the code (the desired section, the index.php file, calling the same component, just register a new information block) and the information block settings ( enter the URLs there)

Every article must have Symbol code.
/articles folder must have index.php with Complex component code bitrix:news (Help URL https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/news.php) like this:
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news","",Array(
    "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
    "...other long records list",
    );
);
?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>

In Articles infoblock settings:
URL IB list page:   /articles/
URL detail page:    /articles/#CODE#/

Watch that /urlrewrite.php was rebuilt, if no, add:
26 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/articles/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/articles/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),

